# Running a powershell script using multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, powershell, import, exchangewebservices, runspace

I'm trying to execute a powershell script from within another powershell script. My current script runs fine, but I'd like to try and speed it up if possible.

What my script does is import a list of contacts into Each users Contacts folder through EWS.

In my powershell script the script that handles the importing I call it like this (ImportContacts is a Function without any arguments):

```
. $rootPath\ImportContacts\ImportContacts.ps1
ImportContacts
```

When I run it normally, as I mentioned above everything works fine, I just would like to speed it up. I tried following some examples of implementing runspacepool in Powershell to take advantage of using multiple threads, but it doesn't seem to be working properly for me. I'm sure it's a silly syntax error, but I have this currently:

```
Measure-Command{
$MaxThreads = 5
$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $MaxThreads)
$RunspacePool.Open()
$Jobs = @()

ImportContacts | Foreach-Object {
    $PowerShell = [powershell]::Create()
    $PowerShell.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    $PowerShell.AddScript({ImportContacts})
    $Jobs += $PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
}

while ($Jobs.IsCompleted -contains $false) 
{
    Start-Sleep 1
}}
```

This seems to do the job, but I can't tell a difference with the speed.

EDIT 5-15-21
To better assist with the question, here is how I retrieve the user data. I have a file I call called "ExportedContacts.ps1"
It's called like so:

```
$Users = & $rootPath\ExportContacts\ExportContacts.ps1
```

The contents of the file is this

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties extensionAttribute2, middlename, mobile, OfficePhone, GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, EmailAddress, Title, Company, Department, thumbnailPhoto | Where-Object {($_.extensionAttribute2 -like "DynamicDistro") -AND (($_.Mobile -ne $NULL) -OR ($_.OfficePhone -ne $NULL))} | Select-Object @{Name="First Name";Expression={$_.GivenName}},@{Name="Last Name";Expression={$_.Surname}},@{Name="Display Name";Expression={$_.DisplayName}},@{Name="Job Title";Expression={$_.Title}},@{Name="Company";Expression={$_.Company}},@{Name="Department";Expression={$_.Department}},@{Name="Mobile Phone";Expression={$_.Mobile}},@{Name="Home Phone";Expression={$_.OfficePhone}}, @{Name="Middle Name";Expression={$_.MiddleName}}, @{Name="E-mail Address";Expression={$_.EmailAddress}}, thumbnailPhoto | Sort-Object "Last Name"

return $Users
```

Then I import those contacts, similarly to how I mentioned above. The content of the import is as follows:

```
Function ImportContacts
{
    Write-Host "Importing Contacts. This can take several minutes."

#******************************************************************

    foreach ($ContactItem in $Users)
    {       
        $service.ImpersonatedUserId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $EmailAddress);
        $ExchangeContact = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact($service);
            
        $ExchangeContact.NickName = ('{0} {1}' -f $ContactItem."First Name", $ContactItem."Last Name"). Trim()
        $ExchangeContact.DisplayName = $ExchangeContact.NickName;
        $ExchangeContact.FileAs = $ExchangeContact.NickName;
        $ExchangeContact.EmailAddresses[[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailAddressKey]::EmailAddress1] = $ContactItem."E-mail Address";
        $ExchangeContact.PhoneNumbers[[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PhoneNumberKey]::HomePhone] = $ContactItem."Home Phone";
        $ExchangeContact.PhoneNumbers[[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PhoneNumberKey]::MobilePhone] = $ContactItem."Mobile Phone";
        $ExchangeContact.Department = $ContactItem."Department";
        $ExchangeContact.CompanyName = $ContactItem."Company";
        $ExchangeContact.JobTitle = $ContactItem."Job Title";
        $ExchangeContact.MiddleName = $ContactItem."Middle Name";

        # Save the contact    
        $ExchangeContact.Save($ContactsFolder.Id);  
    }
}
```

I am also including the File that creates the contacts folder I specify and also deletes existing contacts (if the folder already exists), so that each import is a clean and updated import. I'd be curious if there is a faster way to clean the existing items?

```
Function CreateContactsFolder
{
    Write-Host "Creating Contacts Folder and Cleaning up stale items. This can take a couple minutes."
    
    Try
    {    
        $service.ImpersonatedUserId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ImpersonatedUserId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ConnectingIdType]::SmtpAddress, $EmailAddress);
        $RootFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($service,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot)
        $RootFolder.Load()
            
        #Check to see if they have a contacts folder that we want
        $FolderView = new-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(1000)
        $ContactsFolderSearch = $RootFolder.FindFolders($FolderView) | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -eq $FolderName}

        if($ContactsFolderSearch)
        {
            $ContactsFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ContactsFolder]::Bind($service,$ContactsFolderSearch.Id);

            #If folder exists, connect to it. Clear existing Contacts, and reupload new (UPDATED) Contact Info
            Write-Host "Folder alreads exists. We will remove all contacts under this folder."
            
            # Attempt to empty the target folder up to 10 times.
            $tries = 0
            $max_tries = 0
            while ($tries -lt 2) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    $tries++
                    $ErrorActionPreference='Stop'
                    $ContactsFolder.Empty([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.DeleteMode]::HardDelete, $true)
                    $tries++
                } 
                catch 
                {
                    $ErrorActionPreference='SilentlyContinue'
                    $rnd = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10
                    Start-Sleep -Seconds $rnd
                    $tries = $tries - 1
                    $max_tries++

                    if ($max_tries -gt 100) 
                    {
                        Write-Host "Error; Cannot empty the target folder; `t$EmailAddress"
                    }
                }
            }       
        }
        else 
        {
            #Contact Folder doesn't exist. Let's create it
            try 
            {
                Write-Host "Creating new Contacts Folder called $FolderName"
                    
                $ContactsFolder = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ContactsFolder($service);
                $ContactsFolder.DisplayName = $FolderName
                $ContactsFolder.Save([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot)
            } 
            catch 
            {
                Write-Host "Error; Cannot create the target folder; `t$EmailAddress"
            }
        }
        
            return $ContactsFolder
    }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host "Couldn't connect to the user's mailbox. Make sure the admin account you're using to connect to has App Impersonization permissions"
        Write-Host "Check this link for more info: https://help.bittitan.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008098447-The-account-does-not-have-permission-to-impersonate-the-requested-user"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not at all sure this would work, because scripts you need imported in a main script sometimes rely on a certain order (one may depend on the other) and that order now is not guaranteed I think.. /// `1..10 | ForEach-Object` simply iterates over the array with values ranging from 1 up to and including 10. See [Range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#range-operator-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In terms of the runspacepool; If I rewrote the script to do everything in 1 script instead of going back and fourth; would that work better for something like that?

Comment: It would save some time by not having to load external files, but that would be only a minimal time-saver I think.. Perhaps you can show us the `ImportContacts` function. Maybe that can be optimized for speed?

Comment: I adjusted my question with more information and show the import function now. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: On mobile now, but at first glance I'd say do not use Get-ADUser with properties `*`. Asking for the attributes you need, not all will save time and memory.
Next, you can create the NickName as easy as `$ExchangeContact.NickName = ('{0} {1}' -f $ContactItem."First Name", $ContactItem."Last Name"). Trim()` without using if-elseif-else constructs.
What puzzles me is why you change the attribute names in `ExportedContacts.ps1` and not keep them as they are.. It would probably save you a lot of remapping afterwards.

Comment: I took your advise and upated the get-aduser command with setting the properties I'm looking for. You were right, it cut down the time from 20 seconds down to 2 seconds. Thanks for that. I also commented out all the if\elseif\else statements and added the one you mentioned. 
In terms of the Exportedcontacts.ps1 file, I'm not sure I follow what you mean by saying I change the attribute name? I believe I did that because originally when I export them the export didn't match the categories correctly in the import so I wanted to make sure it lined up correctly.

Comment: Well, for instance, Why does `ExportContacts` return objects with a property `"First Name"` and later you change that back to what the propertyname was in the first place: `GivenName`. I would have Get-ADUser return the wanted properties with their property names unchanged and only map the ones that are different for a [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Contact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.contact?view=exchange-ews-api#properties) object

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I think I understand what you were saying. I went ahead and updated my code and removed a lot of un-needed code. Please see my edits above. If there is any additional optimization that can be done, that would be great! Thanks again for your time and help with this.

Comment: I just had another question related to the runspacepools. Would there be a way to use runspacepools to remove existing contacts from the "Contacts" folder specified, so it removes the items faster? That process takes a couple mins too, so I was just curious.